# Does sw and lw in MIPS store a value below or above the stack pointer?

Tags: mips, computer-science

My professor gave a video that looks like this:

[image]

In the lower right, he wrote `$ra` at location 124 while the `$sp` is at 128 which implies that the first `sw $ra, 4($sp)` instruction stores the `$ra` value at a location 4 bytes **less** than the `$sp`. But my book does it differently:

[image]

and

[image]

The image implies that the lw instruction stores it at locations larger, more positive numbers than the `$sp`. So which is right? Does lw and sw offset numbers refer to numbers higher or lower than the `$sp`?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in observing that the first factorial is storing above the stack pointer, stack storage that it did not allocate, and must have been allocated by the caller.

This is somewhat non-standard usage, but technically legal, since the MIPS calling convention requires giving the top 4 stack locations of any stack frame to the *callee*.  The function is only allocating a 2-word frame, and according to the calling convention (which allows the callee to use the top 4 words of the frame) it should be allocating minimally a 4-word frame.

Still, since the factorial function calls no other except itself, this is ~legal, and in compliance with the calling convention — in the sense that its job is to ensure that one function can call another.

(Note that in RISC V (the open source MIPS follow-on) this requirement of 4-words stack frame for callee to use is not present so similar would not work there.)

---

The second example is more traditional, however, it also does not allocate a standard sized frame — one that gives the top 4-words to the callee.  Still it is also not technically necessary, and less reliant on the original caller (e.g. `main`) providing a proper stack frame (one with 4 words given to the callee).

---

Let's further observe that the first code sample stores `$ra` and `$a0` on the stack, which are registers that we expect to be saved — whereas the latter example stores `$s0` (which we would expect to be saved as these are dedicated non-volatile), but also `$t0` and `$t1` which seems non standard as these are dedicated temporaries.

Comment: The first factorial seems to be storing $ra below the $sp (i'm referring to the diagram on the lower right of that first picture). That seems like an incorrect usage of sw with an offset of positive 4 right?

Comment: The first one is storing above the stack pointer b/c i it is using *positive* offset, AND, it is storing *before* adjusting the stack pointer.  The area being stored into has thus been allocated by the caller, not the callee.  I'm referring directly to the code, not the diagram.

Comment: I see. But positive offset means to go up on location right not down? I think the diagram is going down... is that right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that: up & down are subjective, we can turn the diagram upside down if we like.  It could just as easily be left or right as well.  However, when I say above or below in this context, I am not speaking diagrammatically, but rather numerically: I consider numerically larger addresses to be "up"/higher and numerically smaller addresses to be "down"/lower, regardless of diagrammatic orientation.  So, we (I) say the stack grows down, meaning increasing the stack size moves the stack / stack pointer toward numerically lower addresses, regardless of diagramming.

Comment: I think this is the only consistent way to speak about addresses, that "higher", "above", and "up" all mean numerically larger (and lower, below, and down the opposite).  Some do draw their diagrams with numerically higher values at the top to have a correspondence with higher literally and higher numerically; while others diagram with numerically lower values at the top.  This latter orientation is more natural in many cases, i.e. looking at a structure, object, or array on the stack and/or in the heap, we tend to prefer a "forward" looking orientation.

Comment: So do you see any inconsistency here between the diagrams? lw and sw are using offsets to go higher in one diagram and lower addresses  in the other right?

Comment: Both diagrams have high addresses at the top and low addresses at the bottom.  The problem in the first one is that `$sp` moves *after* two instructions have already been done, and it only shows one `$sp`, so, it might be better diagrammed having an old `$sp` and a new `$sp` (and the two stores with positive offset should be interpreted relative to the old `$sp`).  The second diagram has three `$sp` values, differentiated over time (a,b,c), which is good, though to be clear the actual memory for the stack is the same across them, just the usage and location of "top of stack" differs.

Comment: But in the first, the sw are storing them at lower addresses relative to the $sp and in the second, sw is storing them at higher addresses relative to the $sp right? One has to be wrong right?

Comment: The code sequences are different therefore the diagrams should be different.

Comment: So the first diagram shows the old $sp... only instruction 0 has executed yet. And yet the sw instruction's offset number (which is positive) stores the $ra at the lower register relative to $sp. In diagram 2, the `sw` instructions are storing values above the `$sp` which seems inconsistent to the first diagram. The code sequences are the same but they have different usages of offset... one goes more negative to $sp and one goes more positive to $sp. Isn't this a problem?

Comment: Yeah, so then looks like the first diagram is simply incorrect.  "The code sequences are the same but they have different usages of offset", I disagree that they are the same as there is very important difference: the location of the stack allocation relative to the stores.

Comment: So eric in the first diagram, there is an image of the stack in the lower right with $ra at 124. That occurs after instruction 0 in the `factl` function. That implies that the offset of sw which is positive moves lower relative to $sp. That seems wrong no?

Comment: Yes, as I said, if the `$sp` is still the old/caller/unadjusted value, then this diagram is just plain wrong.  In fact it is wrong also if the `$sp` is the new/callee/adjusted value as well.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the location of the stack relative to the stores is differnet. In the first, the stack is not moved yet before the first sw instruction occurs. That's why since the stack pointer is at 128 and $ra is in 124... I'd expect the sw instruction to be sw $ra, -4($sp) right?

Comment: Yes, but it is bad form to store below the current stack pointer, as that is unallocated storage.  If you want to do that, it is better to allocate the storage first, then store at the equivalent location (of course then the offset will be positive).